# nginx rewrite on heroku for acme-challenge

Tags: php, nginx, heroku, lets-encrypt

I am trying to use https://github.com/dmathieu/sabayon to set up lets-encrypt for my php app on heroku.
Sabayon provides an example for a redirect of the *acme-challenge* call with Apache from lets-encrypt: https://github.com/dmathieu/sabayon#php-apps

I tried to translate this to Nginx but i cant get it to work on Heroku.
Locally it works fine.

I tried:

```
location ~ ^/.well-known/acme-challenge/(.*)$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /.well-known/acme-challenge/index.php?q=$1 last;
      break;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files @heroku-fcgi @heroku-fcgi;
}
```

But this results in PHP code as downloaded file.

I also tried:

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /.well-known/acme-challenge/index.php/$1 last;
} 

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files @heroku-fcgi @heroku-fcgi;
}
```

And this results in a 403.

**UPDATE**
I just found out the 403 is caused by the dot in `.well-known/acme-challenge`.

How can this be done right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several things to take care of:

- the redirect
- make hidden directory `.well-known` accessable
- execute the php file as php

So this eventually worked for me:

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    allow all;
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
    try_files $uri @rewriteacme;
}

location @rewriteacme {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /.well-known/acme-challenge/index.php/$1 last;
}

location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/index.php {
    try_files @heroku-fcgi @heroku-fcgi;
    internal;
}
```